# mass object update receiving "System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded"

Tags: apex, batch

im running the following code in execute anonymous window:

```
List<Case> casesList = [SELECT Id,Next_Milestone_Time__c,Next_Milestone_Type__c from Case where status != 'Closed'];
Set<Id> casesIds = (new Map<Id,Case>(casesList)).keySet();

Map <Id, Case> casesMap = new Map<Id,Case>();
for(Case c : casesList)
{
    c.Next_Milestone_Time__c = null;
    c.Next_Milestone_Type__c = null;
    casesMap.put(c.id,c);
}

List<CaseMilestone> allCms = [ select CaseId, TargetDate, MilestoneType.Name from CaseMilestone where CaseId in: casesIds and IsCompleted = false order by CaseId, TargetDate ASC];
List<Case> casesToUpdate = new List<Case>();

for (CaseMilestone cm : allCms) 
{        
    Case c = casesMap.get(cm.CaseId);
    if (c.Next_Milestone_Time__c == null || c.Next_Milestone_Time__c > cm.TargetDate) {
       c.Next_Milestone_Time__c = cm.TargetDate;
       c.Next_Milestone_Type__c = cm.MilestoneType.Name;                  
       casesToUpdate.add(c);                    
    }
}

update casesToUpdate;
```

i receive the error `System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded`

this happens because i have too many results in the first query.

how can i run this update in batches, in the execute anonymous window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, using this pattern works where you make use of `limit` (try various sizes) but it does require a mechanism to skip over the records that have already been processed which may not be possible in your case:

```
...
from Case
where status != 'Closed'
and <<some change you are trying to make has not been made on the record>>
limit 100
```

**PS**

If you add a formula field called e.g. `MilestoneUpdateNeeded` that checks that both of these are true:

```
Next_Milestone_Time__c == TargetDate;
Next_Milestone_Type__c == cm.MilestoneType.Name
```

then it would be:

```
...
from Case
where status != 'Closed'
and MilestoneUpdateNeeded__c
limit 100
```

Comment: the amount of data is 1000-2000 rows. i still need to run it in batches and dont know how. i cannot add any fields for this process

Comment: @DanaGriff You can write a quick [batchable class](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/asynchronous_apex/units/async_apex_batch) and execute that. Just means moving the query to the `start` method and leaving the rest of the code in the `execute` method. You can then pick how many records to process at once in the second parameter to `Database.executeBatch`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of optimization you can do to try and get through this. I don't know if it'll be enough, but here's a basic optimization.

---

```
Case[] caseList = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE IsClosed = FALSE];
Map<Id, Case> caseMap = new Map<Id, Case>(caseList);
for(Case record: caseList) {
    record.Next_Milestone_Time__c = null;
    record.Next_Milestone_Type__c = null;
}
for(CaseMilestone record: [SELECT CaseId, TargetDate, MilestoneType.Name FROM CaseMilestone WHERE CaseId = :caseList AND IsCompleted = FALSE ORDER BY TargetDate ASC]) {
    Case caseRecord = caseMap.get(record.CaseId);
    if(caseRecord.Next_Milestone_Time__c == null || caseRecord.Next_Milestone_Time__c > record.TargetDate) {
        caseRecord.Next_Milestone_Time__c = record.TargetDate;
        caseRecord.Next_Milestone_Type__c = record.MilestoneType.Name;
    }
}
update caseList;
```

This basically minimizes the amount of work that needs to be done for each case. If that's not good enough, you might go with a sub-query to avoid the use of maps.